# Why doesn't this 'increment then decrement' generic const expression work in Rust?

Tags: generics, rust, compile-time, compile-time-constant, constant-expression

I've been trying to make some of my code more airtight by moving some runtime operations to compile time. I thought it would be simpler because I'm only trying to increment or decrement a number by one, but I'm running into some disagreements with rustc.

Here's a small display of the problem.

```rust
#![feature(generic_const_exprs)]
#![allow(unused, incomplete_features)]

struct Number<const VALUE: usize>;

impl<const VALUE: usize> Number<VALUE> {
    fn new() -> Number<0> {
        Number::<0>
    }

    fn increment(self) -> Number<{VALUE + 1}> {
        Number::<{VALUE + 1}>
    }
    
    fn decrement(self) -> Number<{VALUE - 1}> {
        Number::<{VALUE - 1}>
    }
}

fn increment_decrement<const VALUE: usize>(number: Number<VALUE>) -> Number<VALUE> where [(); {VALUE - 1}]:, [(); {VALUE + 1}]: {
    number.increment().decrement()
}

fn main() {}
```

I have tried adding `where` bounds to this example in a number of different ways but it only seems to make the problem worse. This is the the version of the example that seems to give me the least errors. Said errors are:

```bash
error: unconstrained generic constant
  --> src/main.rs:21:24
   |
21 |     number.increment().decrement()
   |                        ^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = help: try adding a `where` bound using this expression: `where [(); {VALUE - 1}]:`
note: required by a bound in `Number::<VALUE>::decrement`
  --> src/main.rs:15:34
   |
15 |     fn decrement(self) -> Number<{VALUE - 1}> {
   |                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `Number::<VALUE>::decrement`

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:21:5
   |
21 |     number.increment().decrement()
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `VALUE`, found `{VALUE - 1}`
   |
   = note: expected constant `VALUE`
              found constant `{VALUE - 1}`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
error: could not compile `playground` (bin "playground") due to 2 previous errors
```

I'm a bit confused because I've already added the `where [(); {VALUE - 1}]:` bound to `increment_decrement` and yet it's still complaining.

Comment: I got it to compile by changing the return type to `Number<{(VALUE + 1) - 1}>` ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d5b3709d4bbc900190cac70e2432380f)), but that's probably not what you were looking for. I suspect the feature is simply too incomplete at this point to do what you expect it to. You might want to ask about this case on forums frequented by devs.

Comment: You're right that this isn't quite what I was looking for, but you don't know how happy I am just to see this compile! I've been trying to figure this out for hours! I guess the feature really just there yet. Any forums you'd recommend for me to ask about this case?

Comment: In that case, I'm happy to have helped a little bit. As for the forums, you could try the [users forum](https://users.rust-lang.org/) and, if that doesn't work out, the [compiler zulip](https://rust-lang.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/t-compiler). But personally I'd just stick to stable Rust, as for unstable is simply not (yet) part of the language.

Comment: You could also read the [tracking issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/project-const-generics/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+label%3AC-design-docs+label%3AA-generic-exprs), the [repository linked in the tracking issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/project-const-generics/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+label%3AC-design-docs+label%3AA-generic-exprs) and possibly the [internals forum](https://internals.rust-lang.org)

Comment: Tracking issue [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/76560). It doesn't look very active, but perhaps progress is visible elsewhere.